# Quickblox: How to make paged request of Custom Objects

Tags: ios, sdk, quickblox

I have a custom object (QBCustomObjects) for my application which has more than 100 entries.

In my application, I would like to retrieve all of them, but haven't figured out how to do that using Quickblox iOS SDK (using version with latest git commit: Wed Nov 27 18:52:20 2013).

Is is possible to make request using PagedRequest like with QBUsers call:

```
PagedRequest *request = [[PagedRequest alloc] init];
request.perPage = pageSize;
request.page = page;
[QBUsers usersWithPagedRequest:request delegate:self];
```

Or is is possible to make this request somehow using extended request parameters? Something with:

```
[QBCustomObjects objectsWithClassName:@"Movie" extendedRequest:getRequest delegate:self];
```

Or is there some other method to do this? I have tried to read the developer documentation and check samples but haven't found the way to do this.

For the normal requests, I get nice paged result (QBCOCustomObjectPagedResult) on my QBActionStatusDelegate, but really can't find any documentation of how to create the paged request.

All suggestions and comments are appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use **limit** & **skip** params

```
NSMutableDictionary *getRequest = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[getRequest setObject:@"10" forKey:@"limit"];
[getRequest setObject:@"10" forKey:@"skip"];
[QBCustomObjects objectsWithClassName:@"SuperSample" extendedRequest:getRequest delegate:self];
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks a lot Igor, this solves my problem.. I should have noticed this earlier. Many thanks!

Comment: Igor, What if I want to retrieve 10 records from last (Most Recent) and perform reverse paging (I want to achieve "Load Previous" like thing)?